# Format object ToString

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string-formatting

How do I format the two strings **Data** and **Somma** in this context?

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    con.Open();
    str = "select * from Pagamenti ORDER BY [Data] DESC";
    com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
    sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    ds = new DataSet();
    sqlda.Fill(ds, "Pagamenti");

    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Id"] +
            "   --|--   " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Data"].ToString() +
            "   --|--   " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Somma"]);
    }
    con.Close();
```

ToString() is not taking anything and I need respectively "dd/MM/yyyy" and "R #.###".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess that is because the type of the values returned is `object`, which indeed has not parameters.

Try to cast the object to the right type and call `ToString` again.

Like this:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Data"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Or let the `string.Format` handle it:

```
string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Data"])
```

Comment: Do not consider my last message. It is working fine. I need new glasses. accepted +. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
string.Format("{0} --|-- {1} --|-- {2}",ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Id"].ToString(),ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Data"].ToString(),ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Somma"].ToString());
```